# Insert list of elements inside XML tags

Tags: xslt

I am trying to obtain a list of all the elements with values that aren't in the  (Line 1, Line2), and then insert them into the  tags similar to the test.

Right now I can retrieve all the elements, but I'm having trouble restricting this to just my desired values. And then I'm unsure how to match and do a for each on elements outside my match criteria. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Given the Following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Request>
    <Header>
        <Line1>Element1</Line1>
        <Line2>Element2</Line2>
    </Header>
    <ElementControl>
        <Update>
            <Element>test</Element>
        </Update>
    </ElementControl>
    <Member>
        <Identifier>123456789</Identifier>
        <Contact>
            <Person>
                <Gender>MALE</Gender>
                <Title>Mr</Title>
                <Name>JOHN DOE</Name>
            </Person>
            <HomePhone/>
            <eMailAddress/>
            <ContactAddresses>
                <Address>
                    <AddressType>POS</AddressType>
                    <Line1>100 Fake Street</Line1>
                    <Line2/>
                    <Line3/>
                    <Line4/>
                    <Suburb>Jupiter</Suburb>
                    <State>OTH</State>
                    <PostCode>9999</PostCode>
                    <Country>AUS</Country>
                </Address>
            </ContactAddresses>
        </Contact>
    </Member>
</Request>
```

Current XSL for getting elements

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>      
        <xsl:template match="node()">
        <xsl:for-each select="node()[text() != '']">
            <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>
            <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My WIP xml for inserting the result xml tags is below. I'm unsure how to insert the results of the above xsl into  this,

```
<xsl:template match="Element">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    <Element>Value1</Element>
</xsl:template>
```

And ultimate desired output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Request>
    <Header>
        <Line1>Element1</Line1>
        <Line2>Element2</Line2>
    </Header>
    <ElementControl>
        <Update>
            <Element>Identifier</Element>
            <Element>Gender</Element>
            <Element>Title</Element>
            <Element>Name</Element>
            <Element>AddressType</Element>
            <Element>Line1</Element>
            <Element>Suburb</Element>
            <Element>State</Element>
            <Element>PostCode</Element>
            <Element>Country</Element>
        </Update>
    </ElementControl>
    <Member>
        <Identifier>123456789</Identifier>
        <Contact>
            <Person>
                <Gender>MALE</Gender>
                <Title>Mr</Title>
                <Name>JOHN DOE</Name>
            </Person>
            <HomePhone/>
            <eMailAddress/>
            <ContactAddresses>
                <Address>
                    <AddressType>POS</AddressType>
                    <Line1>100 Fake Street</Line1>
                    <Line2/>
                    <Line3/>
                    <Line4/>
                    <Suburb>Jupiter</Suburb>
                    <State>OTH</State>
                    <PostCode>9999</PostCode>
                    <Country>AUS</Country>
                </Address>
            </ContactAddresses>
        </Contact>
    </Member>
</Request>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would change the current template to use `mode` attribute, so it is only used in specific cases, rather than matching all elements. You should also change it to output elements, not text, like so:

```
<xsl:template match="node()" mode="copy">
    <xsl:for-each select=".//node()[text() != '']">
        <Element>
            <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>
        </Element>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Then you can call it like this....

```
    <xsl:template match="ElementControl/Update">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="../../Member" mode="copy" />
    </xsl:template>
```

Try this XSLT. Note the use of the identity template to copy all other existing elements unchanged

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>      

    <xsl:template match="node()" mode="copy">
        <xsl:for-each select=".//node()[text() != '']">
            <Element>
                <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>
            </Element>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ElementControl/Update">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="../../Member" mode="copy" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```